# conditional cumsum in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
   code     rank    quant       sales
   123      1       0           2
   123      1       12          2
   123      1       0           2
   123      2       0           1
   123      2       10          1
```

I want to do a conditional cumsum of sales groupby rank. where quant is not zero add it in cumulative sum on the same row.

```
   code     rank    quant       sales      cumsum
   123      1       0           2          2
   123      1       12          2          16
   123      1       0           2          18
   123      2       0           1          1
   123      2       10          1          12
```

How to do it in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add columns first and then use [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with `df['rank']` Series:

```
df['cumsum'] = df['quant'].add(df['sales']).groupby(df['rank']).cumsum()
```

Or use `sum` by both columns:

```
df['cumsum'] = df[['quant', 'sales']].sum(axis=1).groupby(df['rank']).cumsum()
```

Alternative is create new column before `groupby`:

```
df['cumsum'] = (df.assign(cumsum=df['quant'].add(df['sales']))
                  .groupby('rank')['cumsum'].cumsum())

print (df)
   code  rank  quant  sales  cumsum
0   123     1      0      2       2
1   123     1     12      2      16
2   123     1      0      2      18
3   123     2      0      1       1
4   123     2     10      1      12
```

Comment: What if my groupby is with 2 variables

Comment: @Neil - Then use last solution or first 2 with `df['rank']` change to `[df['code'], df['rank']]`